# submit value from <option> to server no need to select

Tags: html, submit, html-select

I have an example:

```
<select id="to_select_list" multiple="multiple" name="to_select_list">
    <option value="winder">Winter</option>
    <option value="summer">Summer</option>
    <option value="rainy">Rainy</option>
    <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
</select>
```

And I want to when I click on submit, all of the option value will be sent to server through "to_select_list" but no need to select (all) those.

## **Resolve:**

I figured out how to solve this problem at the [link](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial007.html)

*Example:*

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var selObj2 = document.getElementById(selStr2);
    for (var i = 0; i < selObj2.options.length; i++) {
        selObj2.options[i].selected = true;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="tutorial007.html" method="get" onsubmit="selectAllOptions('sel2');">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want users to select which options should be sent, then don't give them a select control. Just use hidden inputs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="to_select_list" value="winder">
<input type="hidden" name="to_select_list" value="summer">
<input type="hidden" name="to_select_list" value="rainy">
<input type="hidden" name="to_select_list" value="Spring">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I used <select> because I need 2 list box and users can move options between them. If I use <input> I won't show list box :(

Comment: @KenPlus — A select multiple already has a means to select multiple items from it, why invent a different UI? Select elements aren't designed to work like that! (The solution is still the same though, when you copy the selected item across to the other select, just create a hidden input with JS at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with JQuery

```
 var optVals=[];
   $("#to_select_list option").each(function(){
       optVals.push( $(this).attr('value'));
    });
```

without JQuery you can use this

```
var option = document.getElementById('to_select_list').options;
```

and then

```
var val0 = option[0].value;
```

also you can send the array to server by AJAX like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {optionValues: optVals },
        success: function (data) {

        },
        Error: function () {

        }

    });
```

Comment: Why are you claiming that the POST data is JSON when (a) you haven't encoded the data as JSON and (b) you are making a GET request? Any why would you involve Ajax in this in the first place? And why are you setting `async` to `false`, that's just worst practise!

Comment: This is just an example.

Comment: This code should be redefined but overall it's a good answer.

Comment: "Just an example"? Examples are teaching tools, they are the worst place to put things that make no sense or are worst practise.

Comment: You are still claiming that the non-existent POST data is JSON.